# Application cache manifest - Content gets updated on server but client does not show updated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

First, I'm sorry about my english, I'm not good at english.

- If server updated content of page (html), then I click button f5 to
  reload this page at client, this page would show the updated content.
  how to do that?
- And I have a json file, this page have a button. When I click button,
  content of json file will show. if I edited this json file, then I
  reload page and click this button, it would show the edited json file. how to do that?
- I used cache manifest, when I changed content of page on server, and
  reload page at client, content at client didn't change.

I executed it on firefox 30, it's fail. but it's good on google chrome.

cache_test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja" manifest="test.appache">
<!--<html lang="ja" manifest="test.manifest">-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    updateAppCache();
  });
  </script>
  <title>cache test</title>
</head>
<body>
  Cache Test v15<br>
  <button onClick="loadJSON('msg')">Load Json</button>
  <div id="msg"></div>
  <br>
  <a href="test.html">test.html</a>
  <!--<img src="1.jpg" >--> //content I want to edit, it will show at client
  <!--<img src="2.jpg" >--> //content I want to edit, it will show at client
  <img src="3.jpg" >
  <img src="4.jpg" >

</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
function loadJSON(idMsg) {
   jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'test.json',
       type: 'GET',
       success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
           $('#' + idMsg).text('success to load: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
       },
       error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           $('#' + idMsg).text('error to load: ' + textStatus);
       }
   });
}

function updateAppCache() {
    // see: http://www.html5rocks.com/ja/tutorials/appcache/beginner/
    console.log('updateAppCache - in');
    var appCache = window.applicationCache;
    // Update AppCache
    appCache.update();
    // After ready to update cache, call swap
    appCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
        // manifest changed
        if (appCache.status === appCache.UPDATEREADY) {
            appCache.swapCache();
            console.info('Swap cache. AppCache status =' + appCache.status);
            // reload page
            window.location.reload(true);
        } else {
            console.warn('Do not swap cache. AppCache status =' + appCache.status);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

test.appcache:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2014-07-13:v15
# AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache

# Explicitly cached 'master entries'.
CACHE:
cache_test.html
jquery-2.1.1.min.js
test.json
test.js
test.html
#1.jpg    //content i want to save at the application cache at client.      
#2.jpg    //content i want to save at the application cache at client. 
3.jpg
4.jpg

# Resources that require the user to be online.
NETWORK:

FALLBACK:
```

test.json:

```
{ "test":"What's up man!?", "foo":"---------" }
```

The content of json file I want to edit:

```
{ "test":"What's up man!?", "foo":"I will always love you" }
```

Answer (score 0):

When something (html, image, css, javascript) using cache on server changes, you need just modify request url to force it reload. for example :

the origin url is: http://www.some.com/test.html
after you modify the test.html content,
the html in client browser will surely reload completely. You can watch the change in firebug.